# Join tables without dropping rows

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a table (Addresses) as described below:

[image]

I would like to select all the data for each user as a single row. I tried a left join and it works well. Eg

```
select A.Address as permaddress, B.Address as mailaddress from Addresses A left join  Addresses B on A.userId = B.userId and B.address_type = 'mail' where A.address_type = 'perm' and A.userId = '987654321'.
```

When I extend this to 2 left joins with address_type = 'camp' it doesn't work. e.g

```
select A.Address as permaddress, B.Address as mailaddress, C.Address as campaddress from Addresses A left join  Addresses B on A.userId = B.userId and B.address_type = 'mail'
left join Addresses C on A.userId = C.userId and C.address_type = 'camp'
 where A.address_type = 'perm' and A.userId = '987654321'.
```

I do not want to do a simple join because it will drop rows if someone doesn't have other address_types. The catch is that everyone has address_type = 'perm'. e.g:

```
select A.Address as permaddress, B.Address as mailaddress from Addresses A, Addresses B  where A.userId = B.userId and B.address_type = 'mail' and A.address_type = 'perm' and A.userId = '987654321'.
```

Not sure if I should not be left joining the same tables or I should just use code to select a couple of times. eg

```
select A.Address as permaddress from  from Addresses A where A.address_type = 'perm' and A.userId = '987654321'
```

and then do

```
select B.Address as mailaddress from  from Addresses B where B.address_type = 'mail' and B.userId = '987654321'
```

then use code to combine the results

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you want to perform a PIVOT.   What database platform is this for?

Comment: Of course two left joins will work, simply add **left join  Addresses C on A.userId = C.userId and C.address_type = 'camp'**

Comment: Can you all the 2 left join code that did not work for you to the question please?

Answer (score 1):

With left joins, all results will be displayed regardless of whether they have values for mailaddress or campaddress.

```
select    A.Address as permaddress, B.Address as mailaddress, C.Address as campaddress
from      Addresses A 
left join Addresses B on A.userId = B.userId and B.address_type = 'mail' 
left join Addresses C on A.userId = C.userId and C.address_type = 'camp' 

where     A.address_type = 'perm' 
  and     A.userId = '987654321'
```

Comment: Can you post a sample output that didn't work and sample table data for that user?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with PIVOT.

Not used to Oracle syntax, but this should do the trick.......

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT userid, address_type, address from Addresses)
PIVOT  (MAX(address) AS address FOR (address_type) IN ('perm', 'mail', 'camp'));
```

[Oracle Pivot](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php)